# How to check connection without change status in ionic 4?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to create an app that this app need to internet, I want to check internet connection without change network status, I use [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network?origin_team=T0K4SHXFW) library, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to listen to network statuses in a component (page) I'd suggest doing that inside one of the page lifecycle events, like ionViewDidLoad() or ionViewDidEnter(). Generally, you want to make sure your constructor is handling as little logic as possible since it will only fire once. You can read more about them [here](https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/).

In my app, I'm listening for network status in a provider that serves as a wrapper for the Angular HTTP module. To get this to work, I had to initialize all of my logic inside of a platform.ready() block to make sure that the device was actually ready to start being manipulated. Here's what my provider looks like:

```
export class HTTP {
  public online:boolean = true;
  public base:string; // this will be set in the constructor based on if we're in dev or prod
  public token:string = null;

  constructor(public platform:Platform, public http: Http, public events:Events, public cache:CacheService, private network:Network) {
    if(document.URL.includes('https://') || document.URL.includes('http://')){
      this.base = "http://127.0.0.1:3001/";
    } else {
      this.base = "https://url.to_actual_URL.com/";
    }

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      let type = this.network.type;

      //console.log("Connection type: ", this.network.type);
      // Try and find out the current online status of the device
      if(type == "unknown" || type == "none" || type == undefined){
        //console.log("The device is not online");
        this.online = false;
      }else{
        //console.log("The device is online!");
        this.online = true;
      }
    });

    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe( () => {
      this.online = false;
      //console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
    });

    this.network.onConnect().subscribe( () => {
      this.online = true;
      //console.log('network was connected :-)');
    });
  }
}
```